# RVM Error running 'requirements_smf_libs_install automake libtool',

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, automake

I'm trying to add an installation of `ruby-1.9.3-p392`, and during the install when installing the required packages automake, libtool, I get the following:

```
Error running 'requirements_smf_libs_install automake libtool',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/1366754296_package_install_automake_libtool.log
```

The log file looks like this:

```
[2013-04-23 15:42:42] requirements_smf_libs_install
  [ ] automake 1.13.1 ~ dependencies... 

  [[32m✔[0m] automake 1.13.1 ~ dependencies   
  [ ] automake 1.13.1 ~ fetch... 

  [[32m✔[0m] automake 1.13.1 ~ fetch   
  [ ] automake 1.13.1 ~ patch... 

  [[32m✔[0m] automake 1.13.1 ~ patch   
  [ ] automake 1.13.1 ~ preconfigure... configure.ac:24: warning: macro `AM_SILENT_RULES' not found in library
configure.ac:372: warning: macro `AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE' not found in library
configure.ac:24: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_SILENT_RULES
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:377: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE
autoreconf: /opt/sm/pkg/versions/autoconf/2.69/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1

  [[32m✔[0m] automake 1.13.1 ~ preconfigure   
  [ ] automake 1.13.1 ~ configure... ERROR(__sm.package.error): 
Configuration of automake 1.13.1 failed.

Tail of configure.log:
./configure: line 2006: syntax error near unexpected token `yes'
./configure: line 2006: `AM_SILENT_RULES(yes)'
```

I'm on Mac OSX Lion, with HomeBrew installed and brew doctor clean. The weirdest part is that automake and libtool have already been installed via Brew. It looks like this was an issue that RVM had but was supposedly fixed: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1803, maybe not for this specific ruby gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem, I just reinstalled from the package on http://www.railsinstaller.org/ and it automatically installed 1.9.3-p392

Comment: On the issue page his comment also said to try `rvm autolibs homebrew`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the actual problem was the macro `AM_SILENT_RULES` was not defined on the autoconf you were using.
You could solve this by adding

```
m4_ifndef([AM_SILENT_RULES], [m4_define([AM_SILENT_RULES],[])])
```

right before the line that uses the macro in your `configure.ac`